Where does the new axes from colorbar live?
The documentation for colorbar says

cax: Axes, optional
Axes into which the colorbar will be drawn. If None, then a new Axes
is created and the space for it will be stolen from the Axes(s)
specified in ax
ax: Axes or iterable or numpy.ndarray of Axes, optional
The one or more parent Axes from which space for a new colorbar Axes will be stolen. This parameter is only used if cax is not set.
Defaults to the Axes that contains the mappable used to create the colorbar.

This is a minimalistic code modified from the demo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

Z = np.random.rand(6, 10)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

c = ax0.pcolor(Z)
ax0.set_title('default: no edges')
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax0)

c = ax1.pcolor(Z, edgecolors='k', linewidths=4)
ax1.set_title('thick edges')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()

In the code above I used the ax argument in the colorbar module. This means that the argument cax created a new Axes in the ax0, as expected. How do I access this new Axes? I want to customize it in ways that are not possible with the arguments of colorbar alone.
For example, I tried
ax0[0].set_title('default: no edges')

but obviously the ax0 object is not subscriptable

One way would be cb = fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax0), then cb.ax for the colorbar axes. That requires a reference to the colorbar, and the access is obviously not via ax0.

fig.axes[2] or fig.axes[-1] maybe. But ^^^ is better IMO.

@BigBen that works!. However, my issue was with a 2D array of subplots, of the form ax[i,j]. But nevermind, following your suggestion I managed to solve my problem with fig.get_axes(). Thank you!
